# Where can I find a list of Android style items?

Tags: android

Where can I find a list of all possible `items` in an android style xml? It seems like a single reference document listing them and summarizing what they do would be an extremely useful thing to have bookmarked, but I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: Android is seriously lacking documentation in this area

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you go for every attributes you want in single file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

And If you want only attributes list then you can refer [**R.style**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html) xml directly but It's not well documented so It would be better to view actual source code given in above link.

Comment: This is pretty old.  Anyone have links to newer code?  Material Design perhaps?  Anyone, anyone, Bueller, Bueller?